# Is It neccessary for a parameterized Constructor in java to have a body?

Tags: java, constructor, parameterized

I want to know if it is possible to not have defined body in parameterized Constructor.

this is my Constructor Below

```
public AutomationTest(RestTemplate restTemplate) 
{

}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine.

Comment: It's possible, but what's the point of passing an argument to a constructor if you are not using it?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It's *legal* but certainly *strange* and at least worthy of a comment.

Comment: Yes, but this looks like test code, and this constructor is probably required by the framework that Alisa is using.  If it were going to end up in the production application, it would definitely warrant a comment - but my position is that _all_ public constructors and methods, other than the most basic ones, that end up in a production application warrant comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is fine. Don't worry about it.